# Ghostscript.NET image text quality issue

Tags: c#, .net, ghostscript, ghostscript.net

I am attempting to convert a pdf document to images using ghostscript. The desired dpi is set to 72px which should be high enough for text to display clear but most of the text is illegible.

I can raise the dpi but that will cause very large image files which I would prefer not to have.

I know there are arguments for ghostscript to add anti aliasing etc (e.g. -dDOINTERPOLATE). How do I add them to the following piece of code, or is there a better way to do this?

```
        int desired_x_dpi = 72;
        int desired_y_dpi = 72;

        GhostscriptRasterizer _rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer();

        _rasterizer.Open(inputPdfPath, localDllInfo, false);

        for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= _rasterizer.PageCount; pageNumber++)
        {
            string pageFilePath = Path.Combine(outputPath, "Page-" + pageNumber.ToString() + ".png");

            Image img = _rasterizer.GetPage(desired_x_dpi, desired_y_dpi, pageNumber);
            img.Save(pageFilePath, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

Comment: What Ghostscript.NET version do you use?

Comment: Version 1.1.9 downloaded as a nuget package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **1.1.9** the **GhostscriptRasterizer** has `-dDOINTERPOLATE` set by default. The only parameters you can control via **GhostscriptRasterizer** class are `TextAlphaBits` and `GraphicsAlphaBits`.

I would recommend you to try to use other classes from the [**Ghostscript.NET**](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com) if you want more control over the parameters.

Take a look at this samples: [**Image devices usage samples**](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Ghostscript.NET/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/DeviceUsageSample.cs)

You can add custom parameters (switches) this way:

```
GhostscriptPngDevice dev = new GhostscriptPngDevice(GhostscriptPngDeviceType.Png16m);
dev.GraphicsAlphaBits = GhostscriptImageDeviceAlphaBits.V_4;
dev.TextAlphaBits = GhostscriptImageDeviceAlphaBits.V_4;
dev.ResolutionXY = new GhostscriptImageDeviceResolution(96, 96);
dev.InputFiles.Add(@"E:\gss_test\indispensable.pdf");
dev.Pdf.FirstPage = 2;
dev.Pdf.LastPage = 4;
dev.CustomSwitches.Add("-dDOINTERPOLATE"); // custom parameter
dev.OutputPath = @"E:\gss_test\output\indispensable_color_page_%03d.png";
dev.Process();
```

When I catch some time, I will extend GhostscriptRasterizer to accept custom parameters in the Open method for the Ghostscript.NET v.1.2.0 release.

Comment: One more thing, if you have a local dll, you can pass your "localDllInfo" to the dev.Process(localDllInfo,....) method.

Answer (score 0):

Got same problem. Fixed by adding `CustomSwitches` with resolution to `GhostscriptRasterizer`:

```
using (var rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer())
{
    rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add("-r500x500");
    ...other code here
}
```